# Show that $\sum (\ln(n))^2/n^3$ converges using direct comparison test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to show that the series
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\ln(n))^2/n^3$ converges using the direct comparison test.

I am aware that this problem could probably be solved using other tests, but as this problem is given in a textbook section for the comparison test, I wanted to try and solve it using the method the author intended (the author implies that this is possible to show using the comparison test).

In a previous problem, I have already shown that the series $\sum\ln(n) / n^3$ converges (using the direct comparison test and the result that $\ln(n) / n^3\lt 1/n^2$) and I have a sense that a similar approach could be utilized for this problem as well. However, I have been stuck for a long time and unable to solve the problem.

I have tried (unsuccesfully) to start off with different variations and manipulate equations algebraically to show for example that $(\ln(n))^2)/n^3\lt 1/n^2$. This has led to no progress.

Comment: Note that $\ln(n) = 2\ln(\sqrt{n})$ and apply your previous reasoning.

Comment: Hint: if $p>0$, then $\ln(n)<n^p$ for $n$ large enough.

Comment: @DominikKutek To be clear, in the previous problem I began from the inequality $ln(n) < n$, and manipulated this inequality to show that $\ln(n) / n^3\lt 1/n^2$. 
if I start with $\ln(n) = 2\ln(\sqrt{n})$, it does not appear to be possible to reach the conclusion needed for this second problem at hand. Can you clarify how you meant that $\ln(n) = 2\ln(\sqrt{n})$ should be utilized here for showing the convergence through the direct comparison test?

Comment: If you know that $\ln(n) \le n$, then $\ln(\sqrt{n}) \le \sqrt{n}$, so that $(\ln(n))^2 = 4(\ln(\sqrt{n}))^2 \le 4n$.

Comment: @DominikKutek I see clearly what you mean now and was able to show what's needed through this route. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We claim:There $\exists N$ such that $\forall n\ge N$,

$$\log(n)<\sqrt{n}.$$

Proof: Both sequences are monotonic, and the limit, $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\log(n)}{\sqrt{n}}=0.$$ $\square $

Hence, we have that,

$$\sum_{n\ge N} \frac{\log^2(n)}{n^3}<\sum_{n\ge N}\frac{1}{n^2}$$, therefore $$\sum_{n\ge N} \frac{\log^2(n)}{n^3}$$ converges, and hence $$\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{\log^2(n)}{n^3}$$ does too  .